# Cloud Build IOS in linux NativeScript

Tags: ios, iphone, nativescript

I am using free apple developer account.
I am using Nativescript Sidekick in Ubuntu 16.04.
IOS device cannot be detected ( OS has limitation maybe ).
I want to run my app in my iPhone.

How to create a certificate for cloud build for IOS with Ubuntu and iPhone with free developer account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot build IOS apps in Ubuntu because you need a certificate to develop which can be created from

- Either a Xcode
- NativeScript Sidekick with a iPhone connected ( Ubuntu OS has this limitation cannot connect iPhones to it )
- You can use the link to create app certificates but you need a paid deveoper lisence for it. [Click Here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/) to go to page.